# Cloudinary recal unsigned images url

Tags: android-studio, cloudinary

i have some kind of issue implanting unsigned uploaded images url recal, the way it is mentioned in this page:
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/java_image_upload

does not go well with the method i used to upload unsigned unsigned :

```
          @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        Map config = new HashMap();
        config.put("cloud_name", "we4x4");
        Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(config);
        try {

            cloudinary.uploader().unsignedUpload((""+ RealFilePath), "frtkzlwz",
                    Cloudinary.asMap( "tags", UserID,"resource_type", "auto"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            progressDialog.setMessage("Error uploading file");
            progressDialog.hide();

        }
        return null;
    }
```

could someone explain to me how and where do i write the code to get and address of the uploaded images ?
i am using android studio.

I was able to upload the a file, and recall its address using the following code, but when i try to substitute .upload with .unsignedUpload as i used before to upload without my full config, the syntax get underlined red ? tried several ways to patch it but not working ? i would appreciate some tips on the right syntax to achieve this ?

```
            Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(ObjectUtils.asMap(
                "cloud_name", "we4x4",
                "api_key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "api_secret", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));

        try{
        Map result = cloudinary.uploader().upload("" + RealFilePath, ObjectUtils.asMap(
                "tags", UserID));


         uploadedContentURL = (String) result.get("url");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unsigned_upload()` method expects the following attributes: `file`, `UploadPreset` & `options` Map, unlike the `upload()` api that doesn't require the `uploadPreset` parameter.
However, both return a response from the server formed as JSONObject.
There you can find all the information required for [generating the URL](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_java/tree/master/cloudinary-android#embedding-and-transforming-images) (e.g. public_id, format, version, etc.)
A code example is available here: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_java/blob/master/cloudinary-android-test/src/main/java/com/cloudinary/test/UploaderTest.java#L67

Comment: Thank you for the example and the clarification